# My Dog's Backlegs Are Hurt To The Point Where He'd Rather Sit Down Than Walk

Tags: dogs, injury

I have a 2-year-old toy poodle named Waffles. He is my joy, and I love him. However, yesterday night, I tried to get him from his pen. Normally he always jumps up. He tried to jump up to greet me but immediately sat down again. I had to pick him up while he was staying down.

It's his back legs. We sat him down and put him back in the living room. He sat there and didn't move. He only moved when he heard the doorbell (tested by my brother), but as soon as he realized nobody was there, he sat down once again.

Last night passed, and he doesn't seem to have gotten better. We took him out. He walked, but he didn't do much but pee once.

I'm sitting with him now. Every time he closes his eyes, I feel like I may have lost him. He's just staring majestically. He's probably in so much pain. Help me :(

Answer (score 5):

Don't waste any more time, but take him to a vet! Animals are tough on themselves. By the time you realize they are in pain, they are in SERIOUS pain. Take him to the vet to find out whats going on. Even if you can't afford an expensive surgery at least the vet can find a humane way to help him.

Comment: Just suggested this to my mom. I'm only 14 and I can't drive. She said my dog is "probably just sore", and when I pressured her further, she told me I'm not going to "harass" her into this and that she might not go today! I can't believe her! What should I do while there is no vet available? She keeps making excuses and undermining what could be a lethal situation!

Comment: @SisterStudent Maybe could you show this thread to your mother, or some source on the Internet how animals could hide their pain and suffering until it's really serious?

Comment: @SisterStudent If you mom doesn't perceive it as serious enough o phone the vet perhaps you could talk her into allowing you to phone the vet or phone the vet herself to see what they say - I initially suggested you because you seem to know more what is going on and your Mom might downplay it to the vet? Good Luck!

Comment: The behavior of your mom is absolutely NOT ACCEPTABLE and you should tell her that in no uncertain words. Since you are a minor, she has the reponsibility for the life and wellbeing of the dog. She is clearly acting irresponsible right now. You could even call it neglect. Ask her if she would react the same way if your own legs or your back hurt so much you couldn'd walk. Please don't give your dog any medication for humans, it could be poisonous. He must get examined by a vet.